# Change font size of section title in document without messing table of contents and headers

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, fontsize

I know this is technically wrong and I shouldn't even be attempting to do it... Nevertheless, I have a document which has section header sizes set up as `Large` and works fine everywhere *except* for one section, which is too long. I would like to change the size of the font **of that section title only** to make it look prettier (even if inconsistent with the size of other section titles)

The only way I have managed to change the size **locally** has been by doing

```
\section{\large{My very long section title}}
```

However, this messes the headers and the table of contents, as the font is also changed there.

I have tried using `minipage` or wrapping the section command with `\begin{small}--\end{small}`, but since the section title size is defined somewhere else, nothing changes...

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % To change header and footers
    \pagestyle{fancy}       % Turn on the style
    \fancyhf{}              % Clears everything in the header and footer
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}         %Page number centered in all pages
    \fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}     %Chapter title in the outer margin of even pages
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}    %Section title in the outer margin of odd pages

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum[3-6]

\section{This title is great}
\lipsum[3-10]

\section{This title is  veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}
The title is 3 lines long! It would look much better if I could just very slightly reduce the font size, so that it fits in two lines.

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\section{Some other nice title}
\lipsum[3-8]

\section{\large{This title is  veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}}
Great! it is now 2 lines... but the header is huge! and look at the table of contents!!

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\end{document}
```

which results in something like:
[image: TOC]

[image: Too big]

[image: Messed-up header/TOC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following: `\chapter[short title in header & TOC]{long title in document}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % To change header and footers
    \pagestyle{fancy}       % Turn on the style
    \fancyhf{}              % Clears everything in the header and footer
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}         %Page number centered in all pages
    \fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}     %Chapter title in the outer margin of even pages
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}    %Section title in the outer margin of odd pages

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum[3-6]

\section{This title is great}
\lipsum[3-10]

\section[This title is a bit shorter]{This title is  veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}
The title is 3 lines long! It would look much better if I could just very slightly reduce the font size, so that it fits in two lines.

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\section{Some other nice title}
\lipsum[3-8]

\chapter[This title is short]{\large This title is  veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}

Great! it is now 2 lines... but the header is huge! and look at the table of contents!!

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is technically the other way around, but helped me solve it... I used:
      \chapter[Long title for header & TOC]{\large{long title with smaller fontsize in document}}

Answer (score 0):

Use  the `\titleformat*` command from `titlesec` inside a group, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % To change header and footers
    \pagestyle{fancy} % Turn on the style
    \fancyhf{} % Clears everything in the header and footer
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} %Page number centered in all pages
    \fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %Chapter title in the outer margin of even pages
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}} %Section title in the outer margin of odd pages

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum[3-6]

\section{This title is great}
\lipsum[3-10]

\section{This title is veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}
The title is 3 lines long! It would look much better if I could just very slightly reduce the font size, so that it fits in two lines.

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\section{Some other nice title}
\lipsum[3-8]

{
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\itshape}
\section{This title is veryvery veryveryvery increadibly and mindblowingly very very superlong}}
Great! it is now 2 lines... but the header is huge! and look at the table of contents!!

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-2]

\section{Some other nice title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, although your answer could also work, I found Superuser27's answer easier to implement... given no new packages are needed, and no need to change back to original format either.